# Processing error while connect to rabbitmq via STOMP

Tags: php, python, rabbitmq, stomp

I tried to connect to RabbitMQ(v2.5.1) via STOMP protocol using telnet and got following error:

```
  #telnet localhost 61613

  Trying ::1...
  Connected to localhost.localdomain.
  Escape character is '^]'.
  CONNECT
  login:guest
  passcode:guest

  ^@  
  ERROR
  message:Processing error
  content-type:text/plain
  version:1.0,1.1
  content-length:17


  Processing error
```

SASL log gives:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 7-Jul-2011::11:43:41 ===
accepted TCP connection on [::]:61613 from [::1]:33387

=INFO REPORT==== 7-Jul-2011::11:43:41 ===
starting STOMP connection  from ::1:33387

=ERROR REPORT==== 7-Jul-2011::11:43:54 ===
STOMP error frame sent:
Message: "Processing error"
Detail: "Processing error\n"
Server private detail: {{case_clause,
                            {amqp_params_direct,>,>,
                                rabbit@skynet,
                                {adapter_info,
                                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                    61613,
                                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                    33387,unknown,
                                    {'STOMP',"1.0"},
                                    [{ssl,false}]},
                                []}},
                        [{amqp_connection,start,2},
                         {rabbit_stomp_processor,do_login,7},
                         {rabbit_stomp_processor,process_request,3},
                         {gen_server2,handle_msg,2},
                         {proc_lib,wake_up,3}]}
```

There are applications running on rabbit node:

```
Eshell V5.7.4  (abort with ^G)
(rabbit@skynet)1> application:which_applications().
[{amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","2.3.1"},
 {rabbitmq_stomp,"Embedded Rabbit Stomp Adapter","2.5.1"},
 {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","2.5.1"},
 {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.4.12"},
 {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.4"},
 {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.1.8"},
 {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.16.4"},
 {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.13.4"}]
```

Same error occurs when I try to connect via python stomp (http://code.google.com/p/stomppy) or php stomp (http://pecl.php.net/package/stomp) modules.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're using version `2.3.1` of the Erlang Client and version `2.5.1` of the STOMP plugin. You need to run the same version of both. You can download `2.5.1` of the Erlang Client [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/plugins/v2.5.1/amqp_client-2.5.1.ez).

Comment: I am using amqp_client-2.5.1.ez but when I copy amqp_client-2.5.1.ez to plugins directory it shows {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","2.3.1"}

Comment: Are you sure you're copying it to the right place? I checked the 2.5.1.ez and the version is listed in there as 2.5.1. Try deleting the expanded plugins directory and reinstalling. The expanded directory is under the database directory which is listed when the server starts.

Comment: I think that I copied it in the right place because when I removed it the startup_log prints:

1 plugins activated:
* rabbitmq_stomp-2.5.1

And when I copied it into plugins 
startip_log prints after restart:

2 plugins activated:
* amqp_client-2.3.1
* rabbitmq_stomp-2.5.1
Is it possible that the link contains incorrect version of amqp plugin?

Comment: Yes it is so. I try to install the 2.5.0 version of RabbitMQ server and it prints
2 plugins activated:
* amqp_client-2.5.0
* rabbitmq_stomp-2.5.0
And all works ok. Thanks for discussion.